React-Native Dialog rendering on IOS
I am trying to have multiple dialog pop ups appear one after the other. for example. you might press a button on a screen and then one pops up, and then you press continue and another one appears and so on.
I am controlling the visibility of the the dialog pop ups based on state variables. I am using class components instead of function ones so I have to use this.setState to set the variables.
The problem is I would just set both of the varibles i needed like the code below, but this only worked on Android and not iOS devices:
Note: this is the "ok" button for dialog 1
<Dialog.Button label="OK" onPress={() => { this.setState({Dialog1Visable: false, Dialog2Visible: true }) }} />

On iOS, I would only get dialog 1 to show, but not dialog 2. to fix this issue, I had to add a timeout. the following code worked on both platforms:
Dialog.Button label="OK" onPress={() => {
    this.setState({ Dialog1Visible: false })
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({Dialog2Visable: true })
    }, Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 500 : 0)
}} />

Does anyone understand why this is happening and if there is a better way to do this?
I have also tried the following and they did not work on ios:
this.setState({ Dialog1Visable: false }, () => {
    this.setState({ Dialog2Visible: true });
});

this.setState(prevSate => {this.setState({Dialog1Visable: false, Dialog2Visible: true } });
});

